# How to make PUT request with cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I have a PUT request:

```
curl.exe -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml" -d @tester.sld http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/tester
```

Now i want to generate same request in php. I do:

```
    $contentType = 'application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/tester');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:geoserver"); 
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
        array("Content-Type: $contentType",
        'Content-Length: '.strlen(stripslashes($data)))
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $rslt = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

And sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<NamedLayer>
  <Name>Dashed line</Name>
  <UserStyle>
    <Title>SLD Cook Book: Dashed line</Title>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
      <Rule>
        <LineSymbolizer>
          <Stroke>
            <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">5 2</CssParameter>
          </Stroke>
        </LineSymbolizer>
      </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I do not get any errors, but curl request above put my data on server, but this php code not do tha same.
There any errors in code?

**UPDATE**

Just now i try use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);` instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');`. Looks like my data sending to server. But i get error: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.`

If i use cURL in console i dont get this error.

**UPDATE2**

I was tried:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
```

But same.

Comment: Have you tried using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` to find out what's going wrong?

Comment: @TommyBravo: Just now i try use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);` instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');`. Looks like my data sending to server. But i get error: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.`

Comment: The error is because `CURLOPT_PUT` should only be used in combination with `CURLOPT_INFILE` and `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE`. I think sticking to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');` is the best choice here.

Comment: @TommyBravo: So last what i can try its line from your first comment?Oh and fogout to says that when i use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` script works 30 seconds and after stoped.

Comment: I found a mistake. I not use this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`.